# Cambiar de consultas en una tabla HTML y SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, tablas

tengo una tabla en HTML conectada a una Base de datos mediante php, lo que pretendo hacer es cambiar la consulta

> $sql = 'SELECT * FROM clasificacionLocal';

por

> $sql = 'SELECT * FROM clasificacionLocal ORDER BY PartidosGanados';

**al pulsar un boton** de forma que salga la tabla ordenada por PartidosGanados.
Adjunto código:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15%" class="posTablaGeneral">
    <tr bgcolor="#83b2ff">


<?php include 'cabezeraLocal.html';?>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php

            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM clasificacionLocal';
            $result = mysqli_query($conex,$sql);

            while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            ?>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['NombreEquipo'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['PartidosTotales'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['PartidosGanados'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['PartidosEmpatados'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['PartidosPerdidos'] ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo https://datatables.net/

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? ¿Qué te ha fallado? ¿Qué has intentado?